# Disable Skype "Click-to-Call" add-in from IE only

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, internet-explorer, skype

On updating skype, "Click-to-Call" add-in is installed on windwos XP. I disable that add-in by following criteria on this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968129).
But, when next time computer is started/re-started this add-in is enabled by default.

How can I disable that add-in from IE ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Open `Internet explorer`
2. Navigate to `manage addon's`
3. Select `skype addon` disable it

Or alternatively you can try [moab's](https://superuser.com/questions/268378/cant-remove-internet-explorer-add-on/268408#268408) answer

If you wish to disable in all the browsers

1. Open `run`
2. Type the following :

   **REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Skype\Installer /v ClickToCallOffer /f**
3. click ok .

hope it helps.

Comment: There is nothing like "Skype Web Features". Only two things are present 1) Skype 2) Skype Click to Call. And If I uninstall Skype Click-to-Call from there. I'll lose this functionality on other apps as well. I just wanted to disable it for IE only.

Comment: @Itz.Irshad  - So just disable the IE plugin.

Comment: But, when system is shut down or started after hibernate. IE again shows click to call option. Why IE doesn't remember the settings after restart ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you run into the exactly same problem as mine. You can use Sip Caller to detect phone numbers on web pages and connect them to your softphone. It's the best addon and it's free. The Chrome extension is available at:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ceiljlhenjgjmffkmfccjoehdpppcgfg

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to **remove** links not add them, and is using IE **not** Chrome. You are answering some different question.